# com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Process ' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

My problem is while adding path to build.gradle , i am not able to run the code.

Below is my build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':android-auto-scroll-view-pager-master 2')
    compile project(':android-mapviewballoons')
    compile project(':android-newpopupmenu-lib')
    compile project(':android-support-v7-appcompat-master')
    compile project(':ImageViewTouch')
    compile project(':pulltorefresh')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0"

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }


    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

The Error i got is :

Error:Execution failed for task ':XXX:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I don't know what is wrong with build.gradle.

Please help  me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in gradle :

```
 packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare multidex support in gradle config.

```
defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```